# Container DIV on iPhone isn't 100% width

Tags: html, css, mobile, width, containers

Take a look at http://benoitfal.com/tess.html on an iPhone and notice how my container div is wrong... It should be 100% width of the browser.

Comment: Do you wan't that grey boarder around the whole page?

Comment: Yes, i want that grey contour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your iPhone is like mine 375px wide - this is 100%. Your images are wider than 375px, so the iPhone has zoomed out to show the whole page. The container is still 100% (in my case 375px), which is why your box is only about half of the screen. If you make your image widths 100% instead of their actual size, they will shrink to fit the viewport.

Original solution for desktop:
Your box is 100% width of the browser but you've added padding of 6px to each side. Unfortunately this gets added to the width which is why it's overflowing.
Set `box-sizing: border-box` on the div and it will fix it.

More about `box-sizing` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Because this isn't a fully accepted bit of CSS yet, you should use browser prefixes as per the example in the link. If you're using Compass for your SASS, you could use `@include box-sizing(border-box)`.

Comment: Compass for my SASS is out of my knowledge :( Never heard of that

Comment: Right, I see what your problem is. I'll add to the original answer, which is still appropriate for desktop ;)

Comment: Still have no idea what to do with @include box-sizing(border-box) ... Compass and SASS mean nothing to me :(

Comment: The Compass/SASS stuff is only relevant if you're already using it, totally optional. Just stick with browser prefixes, as in the example in the link.

Comment: But where do i need to put @include box-sizing(border-box) ? In my CSS file? 

`.container {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #FFF;
 padding: 6px;
 margin: 0px;
 @include box-sizing(border-box);
}`

Comment: because you're not using SASS & Compass, you just use `.container {-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -ms-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -o-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box; }`

Comment: Oh great!! THANKS :) appreciated